# Nix Gradle dist - Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64

Tags: c++, c, gradle, nix, nixos

I am trying to build a Freeplane derivation based on Freemind, see: https://github.com/razvan-panda/nixpkgs/blob/freeplane/pkgs/applications/misc/freeplane/default.nix

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, jdk, jre, gradle }:

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "freeplane-${version}";
  version = "1.6.13";

  src = fetchurl {
    url = "mirror://sourceforge/project/freeplane/freeplane%20stable/freeplane_src-${version}.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "0aabn6lqh2fdgdnfjg3j1rjq0bn4d1947l6ar2fycpj3jy9g3ccp";
  };

  buildInputs = [ jdk gradle ];

  buildPhase = "gradle dist";

  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/{bin,nix-support}
    cp -r ../bin/dist $out/nix-support
    sed -i 's/which/type -p/' $out/nix-support/dist/freeplane.sh

    cat >$out/bin/freeplane <<EOF
    #! /bin/sh
    JAVA_HOME=${jre} $out/nix-support/dist/freeplane.sh
    EOF
    chmod +x $out/{bin/freeplane,nix-support/dist/freeplane.sh}
  '';

  meta = with stdenv.lib; {
    description = "Mind-mapping software";
    homepage = https://www.freeplane.org/wiki/index.php/Home;
    license = licenses.gpl2Plus;
    platforms = platforms.linux;
  };
}
```

During the gradle build step it is throwing the following error:

> building path(s)
>   ‘/nix/store/9dc1x2aya5p8xj4lq9jl0xjnf08n7g6l-freeplane-1.6.13’
>   unpacking sources unpacking source archive
>   /nix/store/c0j5hgpfs0agh3xdnpx4qjy82aqkiidv-freeplane_src-1.6.13.tar.gz
>   source root is freeplane-1.6.13 setting SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH to timestamp
>   1517769626 of file freeplane-1.6.13/gitinfo.txt patching sources
>   configuring no configure script, doing nothing building
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. builder for ‘/nix/store/id4vfk3r6fd4zpyb15dq9xfghf342qaa-freeplane-1.6.13.drv’
>     failed with exit code 1 error: build of
>     ‘/nix/store/id4vfk3r6fd4zpyb15dq9xfghf342qaa-freeplane-1.6.13.drv’
>     failed

Running `gradle dist` from terminal works fine. I'm guessing that maybe one of the globally installed Nix packages provides a fix to the issue and they are not visible during the build.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any working solution. For example, removing the `~/.gradle` folders didn't help.

**Update**

To reproduce the issue just `git clone https://github.com/razvan-panda/nixpkgs`, checkout the freeplane branch and run `nix-build -A freeplane` in the root of the repository.

[Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/34707)

Comment: This seems to be a problem with how gradle has been packaged and/or patched. Minimal example: `NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=$HOME/nixpkgs nix-build --expr 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; stdenv.mkDerivation { src = ./empty-directory; name = "foo"; buildInputs = [gradle]; buildPhase = "gradle --stacktrace"; } '`

Comment: @RobertHensing I don't understand why `gradle dist` works just fine when run from terminal then. Should I create an Issue about this on Nixpkgs repository?

Comment: It even works in a 'pure' `nix-shell` (s/`nix-build`/`nix-shell --pure`) which is not as clean as the `nix-build` sandbox. For example `$HOME` is available in `nix-shell --pure`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem in this case, so I don't know what is missing. This ought to work, so reporting the issue is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just don't have permission for the folder/file

sudo chmod 777 yourFolderPath

you can also : sudo chmod 777 yourFolderPath/*  (All folder)

Folder will not be locked，then You can use it normally

[At least I succeeded。。。]

EX:

[image]

sudo chmod 777 Ruby/

[image]

now ,that's ok

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer to Stack Overflow. Please include the examples as text here in the stack overflow site rather than as linked images.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error: `What went wrong: Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.` do the following:

1. Check if your Gradle cache (**~user/.gradle/**native folder exist at all or not).
2. Check if your Gradle cache (**~user/.gradle/native** folder exist and the file in question i.e. `libnative-platform.so` exists in that directory or not).
3. Check if the above folder ***~user/.gradle*** or ***~/.gradle/native*** or file: ***~/.gradle/native/libnative-platform.so*** has **valid permissions** (should **not** be read-only. Running `chmod -R 755 ~/.gradle` is enough).

IF you don't see native folder at all or if your native folder seems corrupted, run your  Gradle task ex: `gradle clean build` using `-g` or `--gradle-user-home` option and pass it's value.

**Ex:** If I ran `mkdir /tmp/newG_H_Folder; gradle clean build -g /tmp/newG_H_Folder`, you'll see Gradle will populate all the required folder/files (that it needs to run even before running any task or any option) are now in this new Gradle Home folder (i.e. **/tmp/newG_H_Folder/.gradle** directory).

From this folder, you can copy - **just** the ***native*** folder to your user's ~/.gradle folder (take backup of existing native folder in ~/.gradle first if you want to) if it already exists -or copy the whole ***.gradle*** folder to your ~ (home directory).

Then rerun your Gradle task and it won't error out anymore.

**Gradle docs says:**
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html 
-g, --gradle-user-home
Specifies the Gradle user home directory. The default is the .gradle directory in the user’s home directory.